# C++ - Significance of local names for types

Tags: c++, class, typedef

I recently read up how classes are allowed to define their own local names for types. One of the famous examples being `size_type`, provided almost by all STL containers. It was also mentioned that doing so helps hide implementation details from the user of the class. I am not quite sure how this is the case.

What are some examples where defining local names for types might be useful and how doing so hides implementation details?

Comment: What implementation details do you see as being exposed through the name 'size_type'?

Comment: @molbdnilo and which ones are hidden?

Answer (score 1):

> Please provide some examples where defining local names for types might be useful and how it hides implementation details.

its more usefull when you use templated algorithms or containers, which might assume that your type has such type alias. So even if you modify type for size_type - i.e. change for some reason from `size_t` to `int`, then your type will still work with those algorithms / containers.

Otherwise, presence of `size_type` are required by standard when you for example implement your own allocator.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a program where you define several variables of type `size_type` and that it is defined somewhere as an `int`.

Then, upon analysis and reflection, you realize that the variables never assume values igger than 10 thousand. Therefore, the 32 bits used to allocate each of these variables are somewhate an overkill. In this case, you can redefine `size_type` as being of `short` type, instead of `int`. Therefore you will end up saving some memory.

Regarding the examples, you can check [`clock_t`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/clock_t/), [`char16_t`, `char32_t`, `wchar_t`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/is_arithmetic/), [`true_type`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/true_type/) and [`false_type`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/false_type/).